# Adding multiple column names when creating a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**Scenario:** I am testing a code I found at http://www.pythonforfinance.net/2017/01/21/investment-portfolio-optimisation-with-python/ to create some portfolios based on my data.

**Issue:** In the example given, the code is run with 4 stocks, while I am running my code with 779. there is a line in the code that converts one array into a pandas dataframe:

```
results_frame = pd.DataFrame(results.T,columns=['ret','stdev','sharpe',stocks[0],stocks[1],stocks[2],stocks[3]])
```

Is this line, columns are created for 4 stocks.

**Question:** Since i am doing this with 779, it would take to long to input the entry for each stock (stocks[0] to stocks[779]). Is there a non-manual way to do this? maybe with a loop?

Comment: `results.T.columns=['ret','stdev','sharpe'] + stocks`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in `stocks` are columns names and it is `list` you need:

```
columns=['ret','stdev','sharpe'] + stocks
```

Comment: Thank you sir, you just saved me from doing that by hand in excel.